# HSDPA/3G not working and Power off when plugged to charger

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-ace

I am not sure whether anyone has this issue before. My phone is: Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830. 
From today morning onwards, 3G or HSDPA not working in my phone. When I plugged the phone to the charger or plugged into the data cable, the phone shut down automatically. Does anyone have this issue before? Or is there any application or a way to fix the issue or find out the issue

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem to me.

Comment: @roxan: Exactly. The model was for European region :) Now I changed the model :) Thanks

Comment: Well in that case can this question be marked/edited as [SOLVED]... :)

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be software or hardware related. If you power the phone down first and then plug it in, does it start charging or does it do nothing? If it doesnt, I would start to **lean** towards some type of hardware failure (hard to say for sure though). Have you also tried a factory reset on the phone? If it is software related for some reason, then a factory reset may fix that up.

Did this issue appear out of no where, or did you recently install new apps or something when the issue started?

Comment: Actually it happened out of no where. I reset the phone again and install the applications as well. But still I am getting this error